# No persister for entity using AutoMap in Fluent Nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I'm trying to utilise FluentNHibernate with Automapping but am receiving the following error

```
  No persister for: nHibernateSpike.Entities.Route
    NHibernate.MappingException: No persister for: nHibernateSpike.Entities.Route
```

Here's the relevant stuff;

```
        var model = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Route>().
            Where(t => t.Namespace == "nHibernateSpike.Entities");

        model.WriteMappingsTo(@"c:\hbm");

        var db = MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
            .ConnectionString(c => c
            .Server("localhost")
            .Database("PTSIntegrationDB")
            .TrustedConnection()
            )
            .ShowSql();

        var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database( db )
            //.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Route>())
            .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(model))
            .BuildSessionFactory();

        return sessionFactory;
```

Entity

```
        namespace nHibernateSpike.Entities
        {
            public class Route
            {
                public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
                public virtual string Number { get; set; }
                public virtual string ConfirmationCategory { get; set; }

                public Route() { }

            }
        }
```

I'm pulling my hair out. Using the following ClassMap works;

```
        public class RouteMap: ClassMap<Route>
        {
            public RouteMap()
            {
                Table("Route");
                Id(c => c.Id);
                Map(c => c.Number);
                Map(c => c.ConfirmationCategory);
            }

        }
```

I have the opportunity to use AutoMap to drive the DB oon this project, and I'd like to use it - any clues?

Comment: does model.WriteMappingsTo(@"c:\hbm"); write the correct mappings?

Comment: No, I assumed that the automapper had failed to find the types, hence no output. Seems it is a current bug with the WriteMappingsTo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to recall there's an outstanding bug where calling `WriteMappingsTo` can prevent your mappings from being passed through to NHibernate, try removing that call and seeing what happens.

Comment: Bingo :) Many thanks - http://code.google.com/p/fluent-nhibernate/issues/detail?id=325